# how to give edit entry for blog to multiple users

Tags: asp.net, module, blogs, dotnetnuke

hey guys,
i am using dotnetnuke blog module, on my site, the issue i am facing is i have multiple blogger user (the one who can maintain the blogs, they should be able to edit entries and comments.) by default, dotnetnuke gives this role to host, but Blog_Blogs table has a userid field if we change that field, the edit role can be given to multiple user, but my question is i want to give multiple user blog edit role... so how is it possible in dotnetnuke blog module, i am using dotnetnuke 05.06.01 (238)ver.

Please help me how should i go about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the standard DNN module permissions. If you go into the Module's settings, you can specify what roles or users have edit permissions.